# How can I get the iOS 7 default blue color programmatically?

Tags: ios, colors, ios7, uicolor

I'm creating custom elements in my app and want to match the look and feel of the new iOS. iOS 7 introduced to us a very common lighter blue color, the default color or tint for several elements, including the system button, segmented control, etc. They've made it easy to select the color using IB, as seen here:

[image]

However, I haven't found how to easily access the color programmatically. I checked out the [UIColor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and there doesn't seem to be any accessor for the blue system color in the class itself.

Here's my question: does a simple accessor exist for this color? `[UIColor ?]` or something like it? If not, does someone know the exact **RGB values** for that color?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Use `self.view.tintColor` from a view controller, or `self.tintColor` from a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: I was going to say that you can just use `UIView().tintColor`, but in fact you cannot. Not sure at what point the UIView gets the tint color set...

Comment: @DanRosenstark I think the `UIWindow` or maybe its root view has the original version. Views inherit their tint color from higher views in the responder chain, but in your example the new view has no superview.

Comment: `self.view.tintColor` from within `UIViewController.viewDidLoad()` gives the right blue.

Answer (score 234):

It appears to be `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]`.

[image: screenshot showing Colors window]

Comment: Interestingly, the default blue on my system appears to be 0:128:255 (using the same tool). I wonder if Apple changed it recently?

Comment: @JoelH. Check the color space you're currently using.

Comment: Be careful in how you use this, as it may change in subsequent iOS releases.

Comment: Yes, definitely not a good idea to hard-code any value that could potentially change. Especially when there is an API to query the actual value.

Comment: Swift version
`UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)`

Answer (score 92):

iOS 7 default blue color is `R:0.0 G:122.0 B:255.0`

```
UIColor *ios7BlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: And if you prefer hex: `0x007aff`

Comment: This isn't very future proof--if Apple changes the default tint color or lets users set default tint color your app won't get the correct color.

Comment: and in another system: #007AFF

Comment: In Swift:     let defaultTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122/255, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)

Answer (score 52):

According to the documentation for UIButton:

> In iOS v7.0, all subclasses of UIView derive their behavior for tintColor from the base class. See the discussion of tintColor at the UIView level for more information.

Assuming you don't change the tintColor before grabbing the default value, you can use:

```
self.view.tintColor
```

Comment: Looks like the safest way to grab the color.

Comment: This works for me. My `sharedApplication()` does not have a `keyWindow` with `tintColor`

Answer (score 26):

Here is a simple method to get the default system tint color:

```
+ (UIColor*)defaultSystemTintColor
{
   static UIColor* systemTintColor = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] init];
      systemTintColor = view.tintColor;
   });
   return systemTintColor;
}
```

Comment: you don't need dispatch once for main thread stuff. A simple if nil will suffice.

Comment: Why assume the method will only be called from the main thread? The overhead to `dispatch_once` is quite low and is a single if check in the common case.

Comment: @Rick Because UIKit APIs are not background thread-safe, so calling it outside the main thread is not allowed anyway.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov that is true, but it _is_ safe to use `UIColor` on multiple threads. Wrapping it in a `dispatch_once` allows for safely retrieving this color on any thread. And again, the overhead is very low.

Comment: @Rick I understand about the overhead. But you're not just touching UIColor, you're creating an UIView here, which, to the best of my knowledge, is not safe to do on non-main threads. (I may be mistaken, though; I'm not sure where it is documented to check.)

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov from a quick test it seems to work fine. From the UIVIew [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html): "Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread."

Comment: @Rick A quick test does not really help here. However, the docs seem to indicate that your usage is probably fine. So I'm receding my complaint, and I'll just leave a general advise to avoid things that are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 22):

Hex Color code

```
#007AFF
```

and you need this libary 
https://github.com/thii/SwiftHEXColors

ps. iOS, Swift

Answer (score 19):

swift 4 way:

```
extension UIColor {
  static let system = UIView().tintColor!
}
```

Comment: I strongly not recommend you to use forced unwrapping, since it could cause application crash, if default behavior of UIKit Framework will be changed in any next version. Also getting tint color from an UIView instance couldn't guarantee that this color is a system tint color.

Comment: @StanislauBaranouski Why they should change that? Please explain your point

Comment: no need explanation here, it's just a bad practice to use forced unwrapping, especially if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 16):

Native extension with predefined system colors gives what you're looking for:

```swift
// System colors

extension UIColor {

   
    /* Some colors that are used by system elements and applications.
     * These return named colors whose values may vary between different contexts and releases.
     * Do not make assumptions about the color spaces or actual colors used.
     */
    
    ... 

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open class var systemBlue: UIColor { get }
    ... 
}
```

You can use it directly:

```swift
myView.tintColor = .systemBlue
```

Comment: This one will create UIButton every time you ask for systemBlue its better to init this color once. Using internal word in internal extension is not user friendly. Same for using class instead of static. And calling it "Blue" is not right, cause this color can be changed later like in macOS Mojave. So `static let system = UIView().tintColor!` is still much better than your variant.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov you right, better to use static due memory performance. Thanks for pointing to that. But Calling it "blue" still works up to iOS 12 and it's not related to macOS at all. For macOS you have to deal with NSColor type.

Answer (score 14):

Get the color automatically by using this code:

```
static let DefaultButtonColor = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System).titleColorForState(.Normal)!
```

Answer (score 10):

The `UIWindow.tintColor` method wasn't working for me in iOS8 (it was still black), so I had to do this:

```
let b = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
var color = b.titleColorForState(.Normal)
```

This gave the proper blue tint seen in a `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: Feels a bit dirty, but it's better than hardcoding a link color that may change over time.

Answer (score 7):

From iOS 7 there is an API and you can get (and set) the tint color with:

```
self.view.tintColor
```

Or if you need the CGColor:

```
self.view.tintColor.CGColor
```

Answer (score 6):

In many cases what you need is just

```
[self tintColor] 
// or if in a ViewController
[self.view tintColor]
```

or for swift

```
self.tintColor
// or if in a ViewController
self.view.tintColor
```

Comment: self.view.tintColor more likely

Answer (score 4):

Please don't mess with `view.tintColor` or extensions, but simply use this:

```
UIColor.systemBlue
```

Answer (score 3):

while setting the color you can set color like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0 green:144/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: Why is it needed to write `/255.0` with each `rgb` value?

Comment: Because colours on macs are a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a category to UIColor the following way will make it available to you anytime you need it or even change its definition accross your code:

```
@interface UIColor (iOS7Colors)

+ (instancetype)iOS7blueColor;

@end

@implementation UIColor (SpecialColors)

+ (instancetype)iOS7blueColor;
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.22f blue:122.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Once you import the Category in your code you can call the color by using:

```
UIColor *myBlueColor = [UIColor iOSblueColor];
```

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: Uh how'd we get from `blue` to `red` in `+ (instancetype)iOS7redColor;`