# Change Text Color of Items in UIActionSheet - iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, ios8, uiactionsheetdelegate

I had been using following code to change text color of items which I add in `UIActionSheet`.:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in `iOS7`, but in `iOS8` the above code doesn't change the text color of items.

Now my question is how to change the text color of items which I add in `UIActionSheet` using `iOS8`??

**Additional Info:**

I added breakpoint to see whether following lines from the above code get executed or not:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

These lines do not get executed. So, `if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])` is always `false` for all items of `actionSheet.subviews`. So what I think is that the view heirarchy of 
`UIActionSheet` has been changed.

Comment: The view hierarchy has indeed been changed, and you should not be using `UIActionSheet` at all anymore in iOS 8. Use `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to change text color of 'UIAlertAction's if I use 'UIAlertController'??

Comment: @borrrden: There is no NDA this year.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets There *is* an NDA it is just more relaxed.  It still applies to things that were not discussed at WWDC

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465

Comment: For those of us who have to maintain 6/7 compatibility, this is a very relevant question. ios8 has turned even my normal action sheet's text unreadably white and I am at a loss for why.

Comment: Try to use UIPopoverController and create a customize view in it.

Comment: @SalmanZaidi did you try my answer below?  If it works for you, please mark this question as answered - thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25796189/1103584

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's an easy way if you still want to use `UIActionSheet` instead of `UIAlertController` in order to support older iOS versions.

`UIActionSheet` actually uses `UIAlertController` in iOS 8, and it has a private property `_alertController`.

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_alertController");
if ([actionSheet respondsToSelector:selector])
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];
    if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
    {
        alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
else
{
    // use other methods for iOS 7 or older.
}
```

For Swift Below code should works

```
let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "XXX", style: .default) { (action) in

     }

    alertAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Comment: Using private properties will probably get the app rejected

Comment: To do this correct you should use UIActionSheet and UIAlertView on iOS7 and below and UIAlertController on iOS8 and above. For my projects I wrote a 'custom' AlertController that automatically picks the right method based on the OS version. To bad I cannot share but I would definitely recommend doing this also because there are some bugs that might occur on iOS8 when using UIActionSheet

Comment: Will this be rejected by apple? If I use this?

Comment: Great, but how do you know that pro ?

Answer (score 34):

To change the button title color you need to use `UIAlertController` and set the `tintColor` of the main `view`.

Example of setting the button title colors to black:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheetController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"How would you like to proceed?" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *finish = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Finish" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   [self performSelector:@selector(finish:) withObject:nil];
                               }];

UIAlertAction *playAgain = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play Again" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                            {
                                [self performSelector:@selector(playAgain:) withObject:nil];
                            }];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                         {
                             [actionSheetController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                         }];

[actionSheetController addAction:finish];
[actionSheetController addAction:playAgain];
[actionSheetController addAction:cancel];

//******** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART!!!  ***********
actionSheetController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self presentViewController:actionSheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Although, I'm still looking for a way to set each button tint as well as the backgroundColor of the `UIAlertController`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jorge I remember reading somewhere that Apple doesn't want you to customize action sheet / alert colors. I believe that if you want to do more customizations than what I mentioned you'd need to make your own alert class, or borrow one of the many readily available open source options from github.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Actually, I do use `UIView` with buttons for this purpose sometimes, but it would be a lot easier to just customize `UIAlertController`. Thanks a lot. @DiscDev

Comment: This is not working with style `.Alert`. Most likely Apple does not foresee the modification of alerts.

Comment: Can we at least change the font and title color? Apple should atleast allowed us to do simple customization rather than using uiview that would function like an alertview or actionsheet.

Comment: Yes, part of the purpose of GUI (graphical) is to make it clear and obvious sometimes by color, such as when one is about to Delete something, the color red is used to indicate, you are about to do something with potential consequences.  Some of apples choices since Steve Job's passing do not seem wise.

Comment: @Tim the iOS SDK has never allowed you to customize action sheets or alerts colors from version 1.  Doesn't have anything to do with the late Mr. Jobs.  They want a consistent experience.  If you want something more flexible, you'll have to make it yourself.

Comment: DiscDev, thanks, is it possible to change the individual UIAlertAction button different color?

Comment: @Whoami doubtful. Apple doesn't want you to customize alerts/actionsheets.  They suggest you make your own if you want a custom look and feel.  There are lots of projects on github for this, go have a look there.

Comment: Setting the tintColor works well, but the gap between Default- and Cancel-Style-Items is than missing :(

Comment: I had to set actionSheetController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
again in the completion block to have not flicker the color after tapping on the buttons!

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I ran into the same problem but I think I have found a solution:

The appropriate way should be like this and I guess it works in iOS7:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIActionSheet class], nil] setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it will not work in iOS8 due to the fact that the ActionSheets "buttons" is now based on a UICollectionView.
So after some digging around I got this to work instead:

```
[[UICollectionView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Am I the only sees that this changes color for all buttons except for Cancel button?

Comment: This will definitely have unintended side effects and is not advised.  Changing the tint color for all UICollectionViews inside UIAlertController is fragile and relies on the view hierarchy Apple has chosen for the current version of iOS.  As you can see from this answer, they changed the view hierarchy from iOS 7-> iOS 8, what's to keep them from doing it again in iOS 9?  This will surely require updating in the future and is not advised.

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich i'm getting everything in tint color except the cancel button as well. looks extremely stupid. do you know how to set the cancel button to tint color as well?

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich Did anybody ever solve the stubborn cancel button issue?

Answer (score 9):

I'm using it.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Add one line (AppDelegate) and works for all UIAlertController.

Comment: Best solution imo. I added [a few tweaks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29262883/2547229) for backwards compatibility and to get the default tint colour, which isn't `UIColor.blueColor`.

Answer (score 5):

I have same task and I've made this hack today, dirty, but it works

```
class CustomAlertViewController: UIAlertController {

    internal var cancelText: String?


    private var font: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansCyrl-500", size: 12)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        self.findLabel(self.view) //if you need ios 9 only, this can be made in viewWillAppear
    }

    func findLabel(scanView: UIView!) {
        if (scanView.subviews.count > 0) {
            for subview in scanView.subviews {
                if let label: UILabel = subview as? UILabel {

                    if (self.cancelText != nil && label.text == self.cancelText!) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            label.textColor = UIColor.redColor() //for ios 8.x
                            label.tintColor = UIColor.redColor() //for ios 9.x
                        })
                    }

                    if (self.font != nil) {
                        label.font = self.font
                    }
                }

                self.findLabel(subview)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this answer is the best.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `tintColor` of `window` worked for me.

In the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method`

write this:

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This changed the font color of all `UIActionSheet` objects.

Comment: While this does not answer OP's question, it just solved my specific issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 7 backwards compatibility, and to collect the proper default tint colour (that Apple may well change in future versions), I use this. Thanks to the answers about [default tint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19032940/2547229) and to [Lucas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786074/2547229) above.

```
    const Class alertControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController");
    if(alertControllerClass)
    {
        UIColor *defaultTintColour = UIView.new.tintColor;
        [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn: alertControllerClass, nil] setTintColor: defaultTintColour];
    }
```

Caution though – you need to ensure that you use this *before* you start setting the global tint otherwise the `UIView.new.tintColor` will just give you the current tint you have set up.

Comment: This doesn't work for iPads on iOS 9, for some reason. Poo. :-(

Comment: [self.window setTintColor:[UIColor whateverColor]] is the only thing I've found that works in iOS 8 and 9

Comment: @whyoz I'll look at that – I've already set this to something else for some reason, but perhaps I can achieve that elsewhere…

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
    let alert =  UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift you can do like this

```
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "XXX", style: .default) { (action) in

     }

    alertAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Comment: This has been answered above already. Also it will be rejected as already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Note", message: "Are you sure to delete this note?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.