# Is it possible to edit UIAlertAction title font size and style?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertview, uiactionsheet

Now that iOS8 deprecated `UIActionsheet` and `UIAlertview` the customization working on iOS7 is not taking effect anymore. So far the only customization I'm aware is the tint color. And what I need is changing the title's font size and style which I haven't found any way of doing so with the new `UIAlertAction`.

[Already referred to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154889/change-text-color-of-items-in-uiactionsheet-ios-8/25796189#25796189) but I'm still hoping there's a way to change at least the title size and font.

Providing you some of my code for `UIAlertAction`

```
UIAlertController * alertActionSheetController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Settings"
                                                                              message:@""
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction * aboutTheAppAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"About the App"
                                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                                   NSLog(@"About the app");
                                                                   [self openAbout];

                                                               }];


[alertActionSheetController addAction:aboutTheAppAction];
[self presentViewController:alertActionSheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: look at this https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet

Comment: Well that'll work for both since it's made up of a new subclass of uiview but what I'm looking for is ways to edit styling of an alertaction.

Answer (score 13):

You can change UIAlertAction's Font and color.
First you need to add UILabel Category

```
@interface UILabel (FontAppearance)
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIFont * appearanceFont UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end

@implementation UILabel (FontAppearance)

-(void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font {
    if (font)
        [self setFont:font];
}

-(UIFont *)appearanceFont {
    return self.font;
}

@end
```

Category File is also Uploaded on following URL
https://www.dropbox.com/s/em91fh00fv3ut4h/Archive.zip?dl=0

After importing That file You need to call following function.

```
UILabel * appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil];
[appearanceLabel setAppearanceFont:yourDesireFont]];
```

Above code is tested on Color and font. and that will only valid for iOS8 or greater.

Comment: This changes the font for the all the labels in UIAlertController's view.

Comment: Thanks worked for me.  I did put it into my own UILabel category that I already had, and the property declaration went in the .h

I put method declarations for those new selectors in the .h as well

I imported the .h where I used the UIAlertController

Comment: hey thank you the solution just have one query... how we can change the title color using  the above category.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change alert action's font using private APIs. It may get you app rejected, I have not yet tried to submit such code.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Some title", style: .Default, handler: nil)let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some title")

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.5, range: range)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 20.0)!, range: range)

alert.addAction(action)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// this has to be set after presenting the alert, otherwise the internal property __representer is nil
guard let label = action.valueForKey("__representer")?.valueForKey("label") as? UILabel else { return }
label.attributedText = attributedText
```