# How to change font size and color of UIAlertAction in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

[image]

In the image above how to change the font size and color of "Done", "Some Other action"?
and how to change the font size and color of "title", and "message"?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: check this solution  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27518769/2050181

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color/41299305#41299305

Answer (score 7):

This is from another stack overflow post but seems to work fine. [Post found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Dont care what goes here, since we're about to change below" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!"];
[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
          value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
          range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];
[alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];



UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Label text" 
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                //add code to make something happen once tapped
}];
UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
[button setValue:accessoryImage forKey:@"image"];
```

To change the color of the text with the following, adding it before the line setting
[alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];

```
[hogan addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,35)];
```

Comment: And you'll get a crash trying to set value for undefined key on some ios versions (don't remember which). You must also override `setValue: forUndefinedKey:` and `valueForUndefinedKey:` for the UIAlertAction, which you are trying to set image into.

Answer (score 4):

change color a action in UIAlertController

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_alertController");
if ([actionSheet respondsToSelector:selector])
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];

    if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = alertController.actions;
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.count; i ++) {
            UIAlertAction *alertAction = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([alertAction.title isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {
                UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
                [alertAction setValue:color forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to change the font, but you can change the font colour. From the 'hogan' example, changing the font colour on UIAlertAction:

```
[button setValue:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do like this

```
    UIAlertAction * action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ACTION TITLE" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

       // TODO : ACTION
    }];

    [action setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
    [alertController action];
```