# How to make the right hand button in a UIAlertController bold?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a requirement to make the right hand button in a UIAlertController bold and have both buttons side by side. 
If I set the style of both buttons to .default it looks like this:

[image]

If I set the alert's preferredAction to be the settings alert action, then they layout turns to stacked:

[image]

I tried setting the style of the settings action to .cancel but it came out stacked again.

Without writing a custom alert controller, is there a way I can get the standard UIAlertController right button to be bold?

(Yes I am aware the standard action is that the Cancel button should be the one that should be bolded, I've had this argument with the UI designers many many times, they always want the right button bolded)

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you shorten your text. I believe `UIAlertController` internally uses `stack views` and when you set bold font for the right button the width just doesn't fit and it shows up in the second row. I feel like your best bet is just shortening the text, something like "settings" or convincing your designers for the second image that you provided. Let me know  how that goes, I'm really curious :) Good luck

Comment: The `preferredAction` solutions is fine. The problem is your text is too long.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a custom alert as [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView).

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this. There is a [previous Stack overflow post covering this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382034/how-to-change-font-size-and-color-of-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller)