# How to show selected action in UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to achieve the view with a few green actions, and get the selected action to be bold in UIAlertController. And one of the actions, which is dismiss button has to be divided from others and be colored with red.

I am trying to add them with the styles .cancel allows to show dismiss button, but it is bold, but green. 
How do I achieve this?

expected view:

[image: expected view]

my current code:

```
let alertController
        = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                            message: nil,
                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let sortByDateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "По дате",
                                         style: .default,
                                         handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                                            if self.sortBy != "date" {
                                                self.page = 1
                                                self.sortBy = "date"
                                                self.loadTenders()
                                            }
    })
    let moreExpensiveSortAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Дороже",
                                                style: .destructive,
                                                handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                                                    if self.sortBy != "priceHigh" {
                                                        self.page = 1
                                                        self.sortBy = "priceHigh"
                                                        self.loadTenders()
                                                    }
    })
    let cheaperSortAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Дешевле",
                                          style: .default,
                                          handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
                                            if self.sortBy != "priceLow" {
                                                self.page = 1
                                                self.sortBy = "priceLow"
                                                self.loadTenders()
                                            }
    })

    alertController
        .addAction(sortByDateAction)
    alertController
        .addAction(moreExpensiveSortAction)
    alertController
        .addAction(cheaperSortAction)

    alertController.preferredAction = sortByDateAction

    alertController
        .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss",
                                 style: .cancel,
                                 handler: nil))
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Can you show some expected result with image??

Comment: you can set style as .destructive for red dismiss button

Comment: @JitendraModi but it is not divided from the other action if it is not cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:nil)
        cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        alertController.addAction(cancelAlert)
```

try this code.

Comment: Thanks, that did one of my problems, but not the one I am asking a solution for. I am questioning on how to make one of the actions title font weight bold?

Comment: yes, I have tried that, but it only works for UIAlertControllerStyle.alert, and I am using an .actionSheet.

Answer (score 1):

The color of the text in the action sheet is nothing but the tint color of the view. Set this as per your color requirement.

Furthermore, To change the font color of cancel button: Set the value for the **titleTextColor** property of the **UIAlertAction**

*Here is a sample code:*

```
func showCaptureOptions() {

                let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Capture Type", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

                let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { [weak self](action) in
                    self?.initializeImagePicker(captureType: .camera)
                }

                let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { [weak self](action) in
                    self?.initializeImagePicker(captureType: .photoLibrary)
                }

                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
                }

                cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor"). /// The cancel button will be red

                actionSheet.view.tintColor = UIColor.green /// The action sheet options would be green

                actionSheet.addAction(cameraAction)
                actionSheet.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
                actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did one of my problems, but not the one I am asking a solution for. I am questioning on how to make one of the actions title font weight bold?

Comment: The font attribute for UIAlertController is a private property. it is advised not to change this as you will be going against the guidelines if you change it. With that being said, it can still be done. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988639/is-it-possible-to-edit-uialertaction-title-font-size-and-style/27518769#27518769

Comment: Thanks, but it does change the font for every action, but I need it only for one action.