# UIAlertAction change color

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

How can one change the color of a `UIAlertAction` button, that has been added to an `UIAlertController`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. This is an API question which would be the same had you used a different IDE (or no IDE at all).

Comment: Actually no, I wanted to know how you can change the button color of the UIKit from the CocoaTouch framework which clearly has to do with xcode

Comment: This has nothing to do with xcode. Croissant is right. And to your question, you can't change the color of the button displayed by `UIAlertController`. You should create your own alert view or action sheet if you want further customization.

Comment: @OliverBorchert Ya, it's an API question then. Cocoa Touch is an API. You can use it with Xcode, with any other IDE, or without any sort of IDE at all. Because after all, it's just a library and a set of header files which you link against and include, respectively.

Comment: Okay then .. thanks for informing me it isn't possible

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154889/change-text-color-of-items-in-uiactionsheet-ios-8?lq=1

Comment: I have added above mentioned post url as answer. Mark your post as answered and solved for future usage.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37747769/4579593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer following post:

[Change Text Color of Items in UIActionSheet - iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154889/change-text-color-of-items-in-uiactionsheet-ios-8?lq=1)

Although it's related to changing color of `UIActionSheet` items but one user has answered according to change color of `UIAlertAction` items.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. See below for the correct answer.

Comment: actually the fix is as simple as `UIAlertAction.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")`

Comment: **
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Note", message: "Are you sure to delete this note?", preferredStyle: .alert)
 alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.green
**

Answer (score 20):

No need to do some complicated things, you only need to change the tintColor property of the UIAlertController main view like this :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(action)
```

This way your buttons tint will be red (or whatever color you want)

Comment: I had already done something like that - my question actually was, how I can change a single button color.

Comment: Oh, sorry i didn't get that.

Comment: @Sylver You can change text color is red by init style UIAlertAction is UIAlertActionStyleDestructive.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment (deleted), just tried it