# How to edit UIAlertAction button font size

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller

Right now I am using UIAlertController and I am trying to change the font size of action button (Ok and Cancel) but I have not found any solution.

Can anyone provide me a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no effecient way to do accomplish your task.I will suggest you to use standard font size.

There are many third party libraries available for your help. You even create your own by using custom view with buttons with action.

Check this previous [SO ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744237/how-to-edit-uialertaction-text-font-size-and-color) by Kaushal for more details.