# UIActionSheetdelegate not getting subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

In my iOS 8 application I am using UIActionSheet. I tried to change the color of the button title in `willPresentActionSheet` delegate method, but it is not recognizing buttons as its subview.

I constructed `UIActionSheet` like this:

```
UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select an Option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
popup.tag = 2;
[popup addButtonWithTitle:@"Add Tag To Chat"];
[popup addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove Tag From Chat"];
[popup addButtonWithTitle:@"Terminate"];
[popup addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[popup showInView:self.view];
```

Delegate is:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[actionSheet.subviews count]);
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Buttons are showing, I can click and action performs. But it says count = 0. Why?

Comment: Action sheet isn't as customizable as it was in iOS 7. Try any open source one replacement since you are only trying to hack your way which might simply make it crash in further OS versions.

Comment: Under iOS 8, `UIActionSheet` is implemented with the new `UIAlertController` which is completely different and is not customizable in any way. You need to create or use a custom implementation that supports what you want.

Comment: [This is one of the nicest (and customizable) open source action sheets](https://github.com/fastred/AHKActionSheet)

Comment: this will help u. Its works for me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154889/change-text-color-of-items-in-uiactionsheet-ios-8

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, changing the `UIColor` of subviews:

```
    UIActionSheet * action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Title"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"",nil];
[[[action valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I've tried it. It is working...

Answer (score -2):

The delegate methods in which you're trying to check the number of subviews: **willPresentActionSheet** seems inappropriate.

**willPresentActionSheet** is called before the action sheet actually gets rendered.

If you check the number of subviews in **didlPresentActionSheet**, that will be more appropriate.

Hope this helps..

Comment: In iOS 8, UIACtionSheet's behavior is similar to that of UIActivityViewController

Comment: Didn't you read the question? I mention "In my iOS 8 application" in the very first line. I just wanted to know if there is any other way I could do it.