# Is it possible to change UIPreviewAction color?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, 3dtouch

The only options for styling I saw in the API are:

- UIPreviewActionStyleDefault
- UIPreviewActionStyleSelected,
- UIPreviewActionStyleDestructive

Is it possible to somehow paint the buttons in another color? Our designer really didn't liked the default blue buttons

Comment: I think it is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26770557/790842)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change button colors in UIPreviewAction. Even if you add colored images it will switch to default blue color.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
myPreviewAction.tintColor = myColor
```

With this UIPreviewAction extension:

```
extension UIPreviewAction {

    var tintColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return value(forKey: "_color") as? UIColor
        }
        set {
            setValue(newValue, forKey: "_color")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add these snippets on below for the viewcontroller which implements UIPreviewAction

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIView *containerView = [self.view superviewOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIVisualEffectContentView")];
    containerView.tintColor = YOUR_CUSTOM_COLOR;
}
```

In a UIView category

```
- (UIView *)superViewOfClass:(Class)class {
    UIView *parent = self;
    while ((parent = parent.superview)) {
        if ([parent isKindOfClass:class]) {
            return parent;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think i prefer not using these kind of solutions. Too easy to break with iOS updates. But thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can only for `UIPreviewActionStyleDefault` by setting global tint color:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self.window setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    return YES;
}
```