# Using systemBlueColor as a button background

Tags: ios, uicolor

Trying to use [`systemBlueColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/2879260-systembluecolor?language=objc) as the background of a button.

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemBlueColor]];
```

However, I get the error `No known class method for selector 'systemBlueColor'`

If I do a non-adaptive color like blueColor or greenColor it works fine. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That's new to iOS 13.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. @rmaddy Any other way then to set the background to the system blue? (Objective-C)

Comment: Not prior to iOS 13. You have to hardcode the color you want.

Comment: @rmaddy not even if I somehow get the system color this way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032940/how-can-i-get-the-ios-7-default-blue-color-programmatically

Comment: That might work. But if the `tintColor` is never set, and you get the blue by default, then `tintColor` is `nil` and it won't help for setting the background color.

Comment: Wait, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173141-systembluecolor?language=objc says its in iOS 7+? @rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemBlueColor` and the other `systemXXXColor` class properties (`.systemBlue` and other `.systemXXX` in Swift) were added in iOS 13 with Xcode 11. Oddly, the documentation for these colors state they are supported in iOS 7+.

I ran a test in one of my projects that supports iOS 9+ and in fact these colors can be used prior to iOS 13.

This means that those colors have actually been there since iOS 7 but they were private and now made public as of iOS 13. But in order to use them you need Xcode 11 and a Base SDK of iOS 13. Then these colors will be available with a Deployment Target back to iOS 7.

But note that iOS 13 also added several other colors referred to as "UI Element Colors". These include colors such as `labelColor` and `systemBackgroundColor` (`.label` and `.systemBackground` in Swift). These will only work with iOS 13 and later.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Weird that they were private for so long! I wonder if that webpage I linked in my comment is new?